# Building SpiderMonkey with Android NDK toolchain

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, spidermonkey

I am porting a game using SpiderMonkey to Android. Because I need to 
integrate with the game's existing build system, I have to build 
SpiderMonkey using the Android NDK standalone toolchain, not the ndk- 
build tool. Can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this?

I can see that SpiderMonkey's configure has an --with-android- 
toolchain=DIR option, but I am unsure how to use it - specifically, 
which other options I need to combine it with?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the instructions on this page: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Android

Only shortcoming is that it only works with the old toolchain it suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really bad at build systems (especially ours), and I mostly follow instructions in wikis. The Android build instructions for Mobile firefox are available here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android

When you build mobile Firefox it will create the JavaScript shell executable as a binary and I think you can also request a libmozjs.so to link against.